# Woocommerce checkout to process order on an separate WordPress site?

Tags: stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

HOW TO MAKE WOOCOMMERCE BRIDGE !?

**SITE A** : WooCommerce have products no accepted by Stripe
Payment Gateway : WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway Pro "Plugin"
Plugins related to this trick : AffiliateWP

**SITE B** : WooCommerce have products accepted by stripe
Payment Gateway : Stripe "Plugin"

How can I make integration between these site I want to make **SITE B** handle all Payment Process will come from **SITE A**

**Explanation:** when customer make order via **SITE A** when Fill all details for order like (Name, Phone no, etc..) and Choose Payment method (Custom one the site use) when click Pay order the plugin must forward all these details to **SITE B** and direct process payment via Stripe.

I know many sites work like this and I did some research about it, when customer click on pay now it make redirect to link likes this

https://siteB.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/?action=pay_create&order_id=12345&source=siteA.com&payment_method=stripe

I have done research about it right now I don't know how exactly I must make this integration but i know some information may be right

1. Use REST API in **SITE B**
2. Create endpoint in **SITE B** to start receive API request from **SITE A**
3. Send payment request from **SITE A** (handle all variables like order_id, amount, customer details etc,, ) using > WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway Pro plugin
4. Receive request and process payment via stripe in **SITE B**

QUESTION IS : how to make these integration in the right way?